# Loading website content Asynchronously

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, web, loading

My question I think is pretty simple... I have some elements that for arguments sake have individual loading times of 1 second. Lets assume I have 10 of them. Instead of waiting 10 seconds for all the elements to load in order to get the content, is there any way I could load all that content one by one as it becomes ready?

For the record, I am using app engine (python).

I good example of what I am asking would be the following:

Right now I have an iframe containing 12 slowly loading elements. The iframe loads after the page loads, but takes 10 seconds for the iframe to load. What I am trying to do is simply get each element to load as it becomes available (it doesn't have to be in an iframe). Sorry if that was extremely vague.

Thanks and sorry if this question is semi stupid.

Comment: You need to be more specific, what framework or programming language are you talking about? You can always do stuff in the background but your question is generic.

Comment: Sorry! I edited the post. I thought iframes were a clever solution to this problem, but then found out that multiple iframes load synchronously!

Comment: Why wouldnt you use AJAX instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Ajax, look into jquery for a framework which simplifies such actions.